# How to manage interface while In App Purchase is communicating with the Server?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, uiactivityindicatorview

I have my (sandbox) In App Purchase working, but how do I determine if the app is busy communicating with the server? I am having a rough time getting my normal ActiviyIndicator to work in this setting, the app seems to go in and out of responsiveness throughout the process. Then if the user closes the screen before finishTransaction, they can get caught in a human made loop where they might never get their download, if they keep closing the screen before the download is done.

Any examples or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: this isn't a brush-off, it's a genuine query; doesn't apple have a suggestion for exactly this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage the communication by responding to the delegate method(s), and also implementing the SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

If the user closes the app before the transaction is completed, the process will/should be restored on the next time that the user opens the app.

> Your application should associate an observer with the payment queue when it launches, rather than wait until the user attempts to purchase an item. Transactions are not lost when an application terminates. The next time the application launches, Store Kit resumes processing transactions. Adding the observer during your application’s initialization ensures that all transactions are returned to your application.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1

Comment: I am monitoring UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and implementing SKPaymentTransactionObserver whenever the app "becomes active" - but the problem is that the app "becomes active" several times throughout the purchase process (seems like every time an alert is dismissed) - so the SKPaymentTransactionObserver is getting called several times during each purchase... is there a way to differentiate between when the App Store sends a "became active" notification and when the app "became active" from multitasking?

Comment: Yes, have a look ate the UIApplicationDelegate protocol and its methods, to know how to differentiate when the app is becoming active from background or when it's being stared: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It's expected that the observer get notified all the time during the purchase process. it will know when the purchase stared, when it has finish and all the transitions between start and end. Have a look at it's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You have to monitor the transactionState property for each transactions to know what's going on with each one of them, when `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` gets called.